# can i use same webdriver in 2 different scripts?

Tags: python, selenium, import

I am using '**maine**' module for run a script from another one.

**FIRSTSCRIPT:**

```
import __main__
from selenium import webdriver
BROWSER=webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver')
import SECONDSCRIPT
```

but when in SECONDSCRIPT I try to do operations on just opened web page, my error:

> NameError: name 'BROWSER' is not defined

I tried to repeat `"BROWSER=webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver')"` in `SECONDSCRIPT`, but, of course, it opens `2 windows.`

is there one solution?

Comment: What exactly you wanna do ? Is it like in single browser you want to open two windows or tabs ?

Comment: i open a page with FIRSTSCRIPT and i call SECONDSCRIPT which runs operations in the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your driver object to the function in your second script. if you want to access it in the second script.

```
import __main__
import SECONDSCRIPT

from selenium import webdriver
BROWSER=webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver')

SECONDSCRIPT.foo(BROWSER)
```

SECONDSCRIPT

```
import webdriver from selenium

def foo(webdriver browser):
    browser.get("www.example.com")
    //do what ever you wanna do here
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: it will create a new instance of chrome, I don't think that OP wants that. Since he mentioned "SECONDSCRIPT, but, of course, it opens 2 windows."

Comment: ahh i just found out that!!

Comment: thank you. but as i told, if i declare it in second script, too, it opens a second web page. i just need one: that opened in first script

Comment: check the answer now!!

Comment: AttributeError: module 'SECONDSCRIPT' has no attribute 'foo'

Comment: "foo" is the anonymous name of the method in your second script. replace foo with the name of the method in your second script.
basically, you have to pass the driver object as an argument to any function to access it.